# Count minimum time to finish the given tasks

Tags: python, java, algorithm

I have an array of tasks [begin, end, period].

Each task needs to be completed within the time range from begin to end, and the period is the length of time required to finish the task.

1. The period can be discontinuous time
2. The begin and end are included
3. We can handle an unlimited number of tasks at the same time.

Find the minimum time to process all the tasks

**Example:**
**Input:**

```
[[1,3,2],[2,5,3],[5,6,2]]
```

**Output:**

```
4
```

**Explanation:**

```
For tasks[0] we can have time points 2,3
For tasks[1] we can have time points 2, 3, 5 
For tasks[2] we can time points 5, 6
```

So we only needs to be on at time points 2,3,5 and 6 to complete the task.

**My approach:**

```
int process(List<List<Integer>> list) {
    Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>();
    for(List<Integer> p : list) {
        int period = p.get(p.size()-1);
        List<Integer> other = new ArrayList<>();
        int i=0;
        int s = p.get(0);
        int e = p.get(1);
        for(i=s; i<=e && period >=0; i++) {
            if(s.contains(i)) {
                period--;
            } else {
                other.add(i);
            }
        }
        if(period != 0) {
            for(i=other.size()-1; i>=0 && period >0; i--, period--) {
                s.add(other.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
    
    return s.size();
}
```

Here I am trying to add the tasks to a set, and when I have already got the required tasks for a time period I am going to the next task. But my approach is not correct.

What is the correct approach to solving this problem? I am looking for an approach in Java or python.

Comment: How exactly do you know that your approach is not correct?

Comment: @Morph21 in my code, I am checking only the last elements for every task

Comment: to be fair in point 3 you say that the computer can handle unlimited amount of tasks at the same time. So it means that you literally just need to find max period value and you are done

Comment: If it handles tasks at the same time then all inputs will be done at same time which means that computer time of work will be equal to the task which takes the longest time. Or am I missing the point somewhere?

Comment: @Morph21, the longest time is `3` for this example. But it can cover only tasks from [2,3,4,5]

Comment: Yea.. I don't get what the point of that whole code is so I'm out. Why would you even need to write something like that when you have better things already for doing tasks/jobs etc

Comment: Problem link?.....

Comment: *But my approach is not correct* - It seems to produce the correct result on the given example. It's better to explain on the post with a counterexample, not in the comment.

Comment: Could this be a valid input? `[[1, 3, 1], [3, 5, 2], [3, 6, 2], [4, 4, 1]]` The expected result is 2 (time 3 and 4), but your code gives 3 (time 3, 5, and 4).

Comment: @learner Ok but it's difficult to test our instincts then.

Comment: @ILS, yes, even my code has bug

Answer (score 2):

you can find the sweepline solution code below

https://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-question/2770147/an-interesting-oa-question-expedia/1671632

logic

we split the starting and ending pts for each task, and sort them by time.

when we meet a starting pt, we store when it starts and how many time it needs.

when we meet an ending pt, we identify the ending’s corresponding starting point, and check how much time it still needs. we substract its time from all active tasks we met

e.g. [1,3,2], [2,5,3],[5,6,2] --> (1,2,starting), (2,3, starting), (3,ending), (5,2, starting), (5,ending), (6,ending)

```
at time 1, we meet (1,2,starting), start at 1 and need 2 time， stack=[(1,2)]

at time 2, we meet (2,3,starting), start at 2 and need 3 time,    stack=[(1,2),(2,3]

at time 3, we meet ending time 3 for (1,2). res+=2 as 2 is what (1,2) left.   now we remove (1,2) and substract all active tasks in stack by at most 2. for (2,3), we can take away 2 pts.  stack=[(2,1)]

at time 5, we first meet (5,2,starting), start at 5 and need 2 time, stack=[(2,1),(5,2)]

at time 5, we also meet endining pt for (2,1),  res+=1, which is what (2,1) left, we remove (2,1) from stack and substract all active tasks in stack by at most 1. (5,2) starts at 5, it can have 1 pts at 5, so it becomes(5,1),  stack=[(5,1)]

at time 6, we meet the end of (5,1),  res+=1, stop.

res=4
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you're over-complicating this. I think the following solution is enough:

```
int process(List<Integer> list) {
    Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>();
    for(List<Integer> p : list) {
        int period = p.get(p.size()-1);
        int s = p.get(0);
        int e = p.get(1);
        for(int i=s; i<=e; i++) {
            s.add(i);
        }
    }

    return s.size();
}
```

This solution will add all the time points to the set. It's not the most efficient solution, but it's the easiest one to read and understand.

Comment: For Input `[[1,3,2],[2,5,3],[5,6,2]]` required output is `4` as explained in my post. But this program returns 6.